# Positive values only for double in XSD file

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an app that uses XML configuration files, and one of the elements creates a crash if one of its attributes is negative. Right now it is defined as follow:
`<xs:element name="attName" type="xs:double" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />`
If it was an integer, I would use the `positiveInteger` type. Is there an equivalent for float/double ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cannot you just redefine the XSD as follows and use it as a type for the element in question:

```
<xs:simpleType name="LimitedDouble">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Because the value is not an integer

Comment: I modified the answer.